# How to Profile Django App under uWSGI?

Tags: django, profile, uwsgi

I'm trying to profile a django app running under **uWSGI**. [Linesman](https://github.com/amcfague/linesman/issues) looks interesting, but I've got no idea how to actually use it. Could someone help with detailed instructions for this use case? Or direct me to some other better documented solution?

Edit: There are a number of posts here and elsewhere that discuss profiling specific views, django's ORM, etc. This is NOT what I want. I'm trying to see why this **app+django+uwsgi** stack is slow on a specific hardware platform. Since just about everything I've come across only profile parts of django or seem to require running the code in question with a specific commandline, I'm stumped. **I need specific, "for-morons" directions for this specific stack.**

Edit2: I'm working pro-bono on a GPLv3 project. So, unless you also know how I can hack my bank balance :), I'm sticking with FOSS solutions.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I just got linesman at least partially working, by following the [Django notes at the linesman doc page](http://pythonhosted.org/linesman/narr/django_notes.html).
Just add the necessary code shown in the linked page to wsgi.py and start the uwsgi server. After that, go to the URL of your django instance with the **profiler** path. E.g. when you run django on `http://example.com:8000/`, go to `http://example.com:8000/__profiler__`. It's important to note that the documentation of linesman always assumes that the server runs on port 5000 and I initially thought that it creates a small webserver on it's own on port 5000 for that, but it doesn't do this obviously :)

Comment: this is a good project, but its not maintained any more. Works only partially as mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using New Relic.

http://blog.newrelic.com/2011/11/08/new-relic-supports-python/

As well as targeted instrumentation, including special support for Django, a low overhead thread profiling mechanism has also been added recently. Overhead is low enough that can even be used in production systems.

[image: Example thread profiling session results.]

---

UPDATE 1

The point in suggesting New Relic is that it is relatively easy to install and get running even on uWSGI.

For your situation of not wanting to spend any money, it has a free trial period of 2-4 weeks depending on where you sign up through and whether you are trying to claim the free T-Shirt or other promotions such as free RC Helicopter that they sometimes run. Even after the trial period it goes back to a Lite subscription level which costs no ongoing money and which still gives a fair bit of detail.

Comment: Nifty picture. But what I asked for was specific help with the uwsgi + django stack. Could you kindly explain how this help in this specific circumstance?

Comment: Though I did not mention it before, commercial solutions are not a good fit for this. See edit2. Thanks, though.

Answer (score -1):

The Linesman documentation has notes on [deploying Linesman around Django under `mod_wsgi`](https://github.com/amcfague/linesman/blob/master/docs/narr/django_notes.rst). I bet a similar approach will work for you under uWSGI.

Comment: I saw that. The reason I ask is that I need specific assistance in determining how to accomplish this. As in what exact lines to add to uwsgi.ini, etc.